# Android CPU architecture distribution in 2022 (armeabi-v7a vs arm64-v8a)

Tags: android, arm, 64-bit, cpu-architecture, abi

Is there any official information about the architecture usage in 2022 on Android devices?
I have an app which supports armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a.
I want to **drop the support of armeabi-v7a** and support only 64-bit devices (arm64-v8a). But I can't find any information about what share of all devices are using 32-bit.

Everything I found was too old (3+ years).

PS1: Nowadays, x86 and x86_64 are very rarely used, that's why I don't mention them.
PS2: Information from 2021 would also be very helpful.

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
}
```

Comment: you can check 2 answers below, may can help you
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248820/how-is-the-market-divided-between-android-cpu-architectures
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453457/which-android-abis-cpu-architectures-do-i-need-to-serve