# Unity Build on Android - Why use 32-bit?

Tags: android, arm, 64-bit

I have a Google Pixel Pro 7 and just found out without rooting the device, it won't support 32-bit apps and games. So I wasn't able to install the apk of a project I'm working on.
Google states they wanted to give developers more opportunities by doing so.

Now I'm wondering, why should you build 32-bit besides supporting older devices?

Is it true, that most modern devices support 32-bit AND 64-bit?

So what are arguments against building in 64-bit if you just want to build games for modern devices? Will 32-bit still be relevant in the future?

Comment: Supporting 64-bit has been a requirement since 2019 in Playstore, and two years later apps without 64-bit support won't appear at all on 64-bit capable devices. Arm's design starting next year won't provide 32-bit support (though Qualcomm would still provide it to cater to the Chinese market). Even 80-buck dirt cheap phones support 64-bit

Comment: Near duplicate: [Android CPU architecture distribution in 2022 (armeabi-v7a vs arm64-v8a)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74850406) - many people are looking to drop 32-bit ARM support from their apps because mainstream phones have used ARMv8 CPUs for several years now, capable of running in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Usually 32-bit applications have a smaller file size than their 64-bit counterparts and in some cases 32-bit apps are also better performing on older devices that can't utilize 64-bit applications. Other than that, I don't think 32-bit apps will be relevant in the future as older devices get less and less prevalent.